# ActionBarDrawerToggle not found while importing Activity

Tags: android

When I am importing `AppCompatActivity` `ActionBarDrawerToggle` working fine but there is error while importing `Activity`:

> cannot find symbol class ActionBarDrawerToggle

```
 //DrawerLayout
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
```

Comment: have you added support library in your gradle?

Comment: nope, can you plz tell me how to add

Answer (score 0):

You need to add support library in your Gradle:
(Replace 25.1.0 with your sdk version)

> compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'

Comment: You said "nope" before. Anyways see this import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle; in your activity and clean the project, may be gradle isn't synced properly. Retry

Comment: sorry, but i dint got your mean that's why i asked to explain, and then i match you answer to my code.

Comment: no worries, cleaning the project and resync should resolve this.